# Converting ArrayList to a String & Split the results by a ","

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Is there a possible solution to convert an ArrayList into a String & split the results by a ",". So I'm trying to think would I add a "," to the string to use split string to split it in different places?

Like so?

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("person1,");
        list.add("person2,");
        list.add("person3,");

        for ( String strs : list ) {
            System.out.print(list);
            strs.split(",");
        }
```

I know for a fact that the for loop converts the list to a string. I'm trying to achieve these results instead of just getting the ArrayList and having this

**[Person1, Person2, Person3]**

These are the results I'm trying to achieve. (As a string) not a ArrayList.

**Person1, Person2, Person3**

Comment: just iterate over list and print the current index string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.join()`:

```
String.join(", ", list)
```

This, of course, only works on Java 8 or higher.

Comment: Added caveat:  you'll have to remove the commas from the actual data before this output looks "correct".

Comment: This solution is ideal for Java 8 or higher.  Note that `String.join()` does not exist in Java 6 or 7.

Comment: @Ali Dehghani Hmm how would I convert it back into an ArrayList?

Comment: `Arrays.asList(yourstring.split(","))`

Answer (score 1):

Seems as though you want to join the list, not split it:

```
String result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Or more elegantly:

```
String result = String.join(", ", list);
```

Comment: `String.join(" ", list)` would suffice and no comma required as its already present in the source data.